# namedNativeQuery binding not working with payara or Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish-4, payara

Here is the environment setup and the important dependencies :

- Spring boot 1.5.6
- dev Server tomcat 8
- production Server Glassfish 4.1
- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile

***The following code works perfectly on the dev server***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "SqlResultSetMapping.count", columns = @ColumnResult(name = "cnt")),
        @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "projection",
        classes = {
            @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = com.considion.itas.domain.Table.class,
                columns = {})
})
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "Table.request",
        resultSetMapping = "projection",
        query = "query"
    ),
    @NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "Table.request.count",
        resultSetMapping = "SqlResultSetMapping.count",
        query = " count request"
    )
})
public class Table implements Serializable { ... }
```

and The repository looks like the following:

```
public interface TableRepository extends JpaRepository<Table,Long>{
    Page<Table> extract(@Param("para") ... , Pageable pageable);
}
```

---

but once run on production environment, glassFish throw the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property extract found for type Table!

        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:na]

        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:336) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:na]

        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:312) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.15.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Comment: Your repository code looks wrong. Why is it not extending anything?

Comment: I updated the answer, the repository is correct, the code is correct, the problem is related to difference between tomcat and Glassfish